# UITextField to allow ONLY English letters inputs

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, character

I would like restrict input to ONLY english alphabets (a-z) for the username field.  Can someone please help me to add to the code below to NOT allow input of any numbers, characters, and any other languages, other than the English alphabets?

Right now the code below does not allow white spaces and nor does it allow input of more than 10 letters.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
{
    BOOL _isAllowed = YES;
    NSString *nameRegex = @"[A-Za-z]+";
    NSPredicate *nameTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", nameRegex];

    NSString *tempString = [[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];



    if (textField == self.usernameField)
    {
        if ([self.usernameField.text isEqualToString:tempString])
        {
            self.title.text = @"No Spaces Allowed";
            self.title.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

            _isAllowed =  NO;
        }

        else if (tempString.length > 10)
        {
            self.title.text = @"Username cannot be more than 10 letters.";
            self.title.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

            _isAllowed =  NO;
        }
```

**UPDATED**:

```
        else if (![nameTest evaluateWithObject:self.usernameField.text])
        {
                self.title.text = @"Username can only contain english letters.";
                self.title.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

                _isAllowed =  NO;
        }
        return   _isAllowed;
    }

    return   _isAllowed;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't allow to delete first character using backspace.

Answer (score 7):

You could use this Regex to check that the username only contains english letters:

```
NSString *nameRegex = @"[A-Za-z]+";
NSPredicate *nameTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", nameRegex];

if(![nameTest evaluateWithObject:self.usernameField.text]){
        self.title.text = @"Username can only contain english letters.";
        self.title.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

        _isAllowed =  NO;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  With your code, I can't type in self.usernameField.  I keep getting the error "Username can only contain english letters." and no letters show up in the textfield.  I'm not sure if I typed it in the right place.  Please see the updated  Code.  Thanks.

Comment: were you able to look into this?

Comment: where did you use the above snippet?